# Get value under a column instead of columnname while updating in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have `#Temp2` which has columns:

```
Math_Text, Science_Text, Physics_Text, Title
```

I need to run the query below:

```
update t
set CombinedText = t2.Title + '_Text'
from #Temp1 t
inner #Temp2 t2 on t2.Id = t.Id
```

When I run it, for example, I see CombinedText = 'Math_Text' but I need the actual value under that column. What can I do? Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'update t
    set CombinedText = t2.Title + ''_Text''
    from #Temp1 t
    inner #Temp2 t2 on t2.Id = t.Id
'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

did not work as well, t2.Title stays instead turning into its actual value.

EDIT2:

`set CombinedText = c.[t2.Title+''_Text'']`  also did not work

Comment: It appears you are trying to dynamically build the column name you wish to query, the only way to do that is using dynamic SQL

Comment: @DaleBurrell Could u please show me how I can build it for this example?

Comment: You need to do some research yourself, google dynamic SQL, have a go, then post any questions back.

Comment: @DaleBurrell doing it now, updated my answer. still couldn't fix but on it. thanks for advice

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results to your question - I can't quite work out what your end goal is here.

Comment: Why do you have several rows with 'Title=[Math], Math_Text=[V], Sci_Text=NULL, Phy_Text=NULL', another several rows with 'Title=[Sci], Math_Text=NULL, Sci_Text=[V], Phy_Text=NULL', etc., instead of 'Title=[Math, Sci OR Phy], CombinedText=[V]'?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very poor data design.  You should have your "text" columns in separate rows rather than columns.

With that in mind, you could do:

```
update t
    set CombinedText = v.txt
    from #Temp1 t inner join
         #Temp2 t2
         on t2.Id = t.Id cross apply
         (select v.*
          from (values ('Math', Math_Text), ('Science', Science_Text), ('Physics', Physics_Text)
               ) v(title, txt)
          where v.title = t2.title
         );
```

You could also use a giant `case` expression.